# How do code inline css with html on Wix newsletter?

Tags: html, inline-styles

I tried to use the html and use inline CSS to code, but when it's in preview it doesn't work. It gets shoved down lower than on the editing page.

Here's my code:

```html
<p style ="border:0; padding-top: 20px;">

<a href="https://www.savanhwellness.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/2ffbb9_11c1aae28c5f43f2b5122067a7f9a34e~mv2.png" width="200" height alt="Savanh Wellness Logo"></a>

  <a href="https://www.savanhwellness.com/shop-all" style="color:black; padding-left: 150px; font-family: 'Montserrat'; margin-top: -50">    SHOP</a>

<a href="https://www.savanhwellness.com/aapi-cc" style="color:black; font-family: 'Montserrat'">    AAPI-CC</a>

<a href="https://www.savanhwellness.com/contact" style="color:black; font-family: 'Montserrat'">    CONTACT</a>
</h3>

</p>
```

Edit page
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNmAv.png

Preview
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igxhw.png

Answer (score 0):

I made a few adjustments to your HTML code:

- Added the style attribute to the

  tag to include the inline CSS. There was an space between the equal sign and the style attribute
- Fixed the  tag, which was not opened correctly and removed it as it seems to be unnecessary in this context.
- Added proper units (e.g., "px" for margin-top) where needed.
- Closed the  tag with /> for proper HTML syntax.

Now, your HTML code should apply the specified inline CSS styles to the respective elements in your Wix newsletter. Make sure to paste this modified code into the HTML Settings of your Wix newsletter where you want to apply these styles.

```html
<p style="border: 0; padding-top: 20px;">
  <a href="https://www.savanhwellness.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/2ffbb9_11c1aae28c5f43f2b5122067a7f9a34e~mv2.png" width="200" height alt="Savanh Wellness Logo" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.savanhwellness.com/shop-all" style="color: black; padding-left: 150px; font-family: 'Montserrat'; margin-top: -50px;">SHOP</a>

  <a href="https://www.savanhwellness.com/aapi-cc" style="color: black; font-family: 'Montserrat';">AAPI-CC</a>

  <a href="https://www.savanhwellness.com/contact" style="color: black; font-family: 'Montserrat';">CONTACT</a>
</p>
```